# NGINX - different backend proxy based on query parameter

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I've got a particular scenario where I'm needing to route to a different backend based on query parameter:

```
https://edge1.cdn.com/file.zip?{secure_link}&{tokens}&route=aws1
```

Where aws1 would be say http://edge1.amazonwebservices.com

and if its aws2 then proxy backend would be http://edge2.amazonwebservices.com

and so on... but I still have not figured out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive to get a proxy hostname from the [`$arg_route`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) variable (which contains a value of the `route` query argument):

```
map $arg_route $aws {
    aws1    edge1.amazonwebservices.com;
    aws2    edge2.amazonwebservices.com;
    ...
    default <default_hostname>;
}

server {
    ...
    # if you want to proxy the request, you'd need a 'resolver' directive
    resolver <some_working_DNS_server_address>;

    location / {
        # if you want to proxy the request
        proxy_pass http://$aws;
        # or if you want to redirect the request
        rewrite ^ http://$aws$uri permanent;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to serve the request without `route` query argument, you can omit the last `default` line at the `map` block and add the following `if` block to your server configuration:

```
if ($aws = '') {
    return 403; # HTTP 403 denied
}
```

If you need to proxy the request you'd additionally need a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive (you can read some technical details about it in [this](http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html) article).

Comment: Anything helpful in the nginx error log?

Comment: I got excited with the first part of the answer that I forgot to read the last part of the resolver configuration, found it :) and now working like charm. thanks

Comment: Yes, I'd better add an example to the nginx configuration. Done. BTW, StackOverflow way of thanking for the answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour#:~:text=The%20person%20who%20asked%20can%20mark%20one%20answer%20as%20%22accepted%22.) :)